# How did Rita get back on the Wanderer?

Tags: plot-explanation, wild-wild-west

In *Wild Wild West*, after they leave Rita at the train station, The Wanderer heads  down the track with Gordon staring longingly after Rita.

Moments later, Rita drops through the roof of the Wanderer and onto a seat next to West. I didn't see any sign of her as the train speeds away, although it is admittedly a dark scene.

How did Rita get back on the train?